WPF Test Validation Rule with Data in BindingExpression
I have the following Problem, I would like to test if a ValidationRule in WPF works as expected.
My ValidationRule use some Data from the DataItem defined in BindingExpression.
It's not a problem to call the Validate Function, but I don't have a plan how to setup a mock for the BindingExpression parameter.
I tried to create a Mock using Moq, but it's a sealed class, therefore this is not possible.
I tried to create an instance using the constructor, but the constructor is internal, therefore this is not possible too.
Is there any solution how I can setup a BindingExpression, too overgive some data inside for testing?

What kind of testing? For unit tests just create an instance and call public methods.

More details would be splendid! Because ValidationRule does not provide a method that accepts a BindingExpression. And what are the information you need from the bindingExpression? Can't you just strip it and pass them explicitly as arguments instead of unwrapping them in your validation rule? This way you eliminate the dependency on the type. Why do you validate the Binding in the first place? Data validation should be about data and not framework infrastructure.

@Sinatr Yes, UnitTesting, the problem is that I can create a instance of the ValidationRule, but I can't create a Instance of the Parameter BindingExpression which holds the Context of the View in my context the ViewModel to be more concrete

@BionicCode For the argument ValidationRule does not provide a Methode that accepts a Binding expression, it does Validate(Object, CultureInfo, BindingExpressionBase), can also be found on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validationrule?view=windowsdesktop-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=netstandard-2.1

@BionicCode I am not checking the infrastruction only the data inside vmModel, if Field A is A or B my field is allowed to be true, otherwise my field is not allowed to be true. Would maybe possible to overgive more variables, but, don't know how to bring WPF to pass more fields to my ValidationRule and don't want to change my code to be able to test it (another rule of good testing)

@Franz Yes, you are right. There exists a corresponding overload. What data exactly are you using of BindingExpression? The resolved path? Do you want to use reflection to reference the property of the binding source to check its value? But that value is passed to the ValidationRule. It's what is validated. Or do you use the binding source object to inspect other members e.g. private fields using reflection? Can you please elaborate more on what exactly you are doing with the BindingExpression, what data you are using? I can suggest a solution based on that information.

You shouldn't test interactions in unit tests imho. Refactor your validation rule to have simple logic you test in unit tests and let the rest to be tested by integration tests.

If you can't mock a parameter, you can always introduce an intermediate method that accepts the unwrapped data. The inherited API must be delegated to this new intermediate API. You can also convert the data to a new type instead of unwrapping it.
The key is to not add any functionality to the inherited methods. If you need to call the base implementation, you must do this from the intermediate API.
The following example shows how to convert the data to a mockable object so that you can properly test the behavior:
ExampleValidationRule.cs
class ExampleValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
  // The inherited method does nothing except converting the parameters 
  // and delegating all functionality to a new method (the method that is actually tested).
  public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo, BindingExpressionBase owner)
  {
    // Store the required information in the BindingInfo.
    // Consider using a constructor over the initializer for more convenience.
    var bindingInfo = new BindingInfo()
    {
      Source = ((BindingExpression)owner).ResolvedSource
    };

    // And delegate to a custom API
    return Validate(value, cultureInfo, bindingInfo);

    // Do not call any base implementations from the delegating method
    // as the delegating method must not contain or execute any functionality
    //base.Validate(value, cultueInfo, bindingExpression);
  }

  // Use this method to test the Validate override. Here you can mock the BindingInfo if required.
  // From an internal point of view or design perspective, 
  // this method is the true entry point of the validation logic. 
  // The inherited base methods are only!!! used to delegate the parameters to this method.
  // This allows to ignore the inherited Validate methods in your unit test
  // as they contain no functionality.
  public ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo, BindingInfo owner)
  {
    // Call base implementations from here if required
    base.Validate(value, cultureInfo);

    // TODO::Implemet the validation here
  }
}

BindingInfo.cs
The mockable class or struct that holds the relevant information of a BindingExpression.
Consider using a constructor for more convenience in application code but use overloads that avoid BindingExpressionBase or the object initializer in test code.
class BindingInfo
{
  public object Source { get; init set; }

  public BindingInfo(BindingExpressionBase bindingExpressionBase)
  {
    // For the sake of an example
    this.Source = bindingExpressionBase is BindingExpression bindingExpression
      ? bindingExpression.ResolvedSource
      : null;
  }
}

